# NUnit Has.Member fails when checking for object

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, ienumerable

I have the following NUnit test:

```
[Test]
    public void GetComplexRulesTestContents()
    {
        var _rule = new RuleViewModel(null, "third rule", "description");
        var result = _complexRulesService.GetComplexRules();

        Assert.That(result, Has.Member(_rule));

    }
```

The code called from _complexRulesService.GetComplexRules() is:

```
public IEnumerable<IRuleViewModel> GetComplexRules()
    {

        IEnumerable<RuleViewModel> _rules;
        _rules = new List<RuleViewModel>
                     {
                         new RuleViewModel(null, "first default rule", "description"),
                         new RuleViewModel(null, "second default rule", "description"),
                         new RuleViewModel(null, "third rule", "description")
                     };
        return _rules;
    }
```

the error message I get is:

```
PL.Web.MVC.Rules.Tests.ComplexRulesServiceTests.GetComplexRulesTestContents:
Expected: collection containing <PL.Web.MVC.Models.Rules.RuleViewModel>
But was:  < <PL.Web.MVC.Models.Rules.RuleViewModel>, PL.Web.MVC.Models.Rules.RuleViewModel>, <PL.Web.MVC.Models.Rules.RuleViewModel> >
```

I have tried the tests from http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=collectionConstraints&r=2.5.5 and they all pass.

What is it I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Has.Member` uses object equality to verify whether collection contains item:

> For references, Has.Member uses object equality to find a member in a collection.

What that means is, your classes will be compared for equality using default equality comparision, which (unless you override it) is object reference equality. And those are all 4 different instances.

You can perform simple predicate matching with bit of LINQ to solve your problem:

```
var expectedItem = results.FirstOrDefault(vm => vm.Property1 == null
    && vm.Name == "third rule" && vm.Description == "description");
Assert.That(expectedItem, Is.Not.Null);
```

Or, to make it more neat you can add custom equality comparison method to your tests class and use it with predicate matching for bit more fluency:

```
private bool RulesMatch(RuleViewModel actual, RuleViewModel expected)
{
    return actual.Property1 == expected.Property1
        && actual.Name == expected.Name
        && actual.Description == expected.Description;
}

Assert.That(results, Has.Some.Matches<RuleViewModel>(v => RulesMatch(v, _rule)));
```

Comment: Thanks jimmy_keen. In order to get it working in the meantime I overrode the default equality comparison in the custom class and check for array.Contains(var), which worked with an Assert. Thanks for the clarification, I was curious as to whether or not it was doing something 'special' behind the scenes.